# Analyze a field twice and store results together with elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, analyzer

Is it possible to analyze a field that has already been analyzed?

For example, suppose we broke down `/Health & Beauty/Vitamins & Supplements/Supplements` into the following using a custom analysis with a hierarchical token:
`/Health & Beauty`
`/Health & Beauty/Vitamins & Supplements`
`/Health & Beauty/Vitamins & Supplements/Supplements`

Would it be possible to then run a separate analysis on each new string and store the results with the corresponding string?

How would we do that with the following mapping:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "path-analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "path-tokenizer"
        },
        "url-analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter" : ["urlFormat"],
          "filter": ["lowercase"],
          "tokenizer": "path-tokenizer"
        },
        "cat-analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter" : ["catName"],
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "char_filter" : {
        "urlFormat":{
          "type":"pattern_replace",
          "pattern":"[^a-z|A-Z|/]+",
          "replacement":"-"
        },
        "catName":{
          "type":"pattern_replace",
          "pattern":"[^/]+/",
          "replacement":""
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "path-tokenizer": {
          "type": "path_hierarchy"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
        "group_path": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": "url-analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string",
              "index_analyzer": "cat-analyzer",
              "search_analyzer": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for your consideration

Comment: Not quite. But what are you trying to do? What is the use-case?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thanks for the response. Mostly for aggregations, I am trying to store a **name** with each **path** so that when a tokenized **path** is aggregated, it can also return a **name** with the **path**. Fe. if the tokenized **path** `/health-beauty/vitamins-supplements` was chosen, it would also be able to return the **name** `Vitamins & Supplements` which would have been stored with the **path**.